# Error LNK2019 and LNK2001: unresolved external symbol with Phonon in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, dll, cmake, phonon

I have gone through all the suggestions relating to  LNK2019 and  LNK2001 but non appear to solve my problem. My problem have to do with phonon and DLL but I can't figure out how to link the necessary library because my project doesn't have `.pro` file.
I'm using vsaddin and vs2010, and cmake. The cmake does have a line as follow:

```
set( QT_LIBS QtCore QtGui QtNetwork QtSvg QtWebKit QtXml QtXmlPatterns phonon )
```

The error I got is as follow:

```
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Phonon::Path::~Path(void)" (__imp_??1Path@Phonon@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QString const &,class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@ABVQString@@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class Phonon::Path __cdecl Phonon::createPath(class Phonon::MediaNode *,class Phonon::MediaNode *)" (__imp_?createPath@Phonon@@YA?AVPath@1@PAVMediaNode@1@0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QString const &,class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@ABVQString@@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Phonon::MediaObject::setTickInterval(int)" (__imp_?setTickInterval@MediaObject@Phonon@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QString const &,class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@ABVQString@@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)

...

12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Phonon::AudioOutput::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@AudioOutput@Phonon@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall Phonon::AudioOutput::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@AudioOutput@Phonon@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Phonon::AudioOutput::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@AudioOutput@Phonon@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Phonon::MediaObject::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MediaObject@Phonon@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall Phonon::MediaObject::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MediaObject@Phonon@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
12>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Phonon::MediaObject::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MediaObject@Phonon@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

...

12>F:\Projects\build_0.02_audio\bin\Debug\Rashomon.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 37 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'm experiencing same issues on my project and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `set()` command sets a variable. To link your executable with these libs you need

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable ${QT_LIBS})
```